# MYSQL Insert w. Unknown Amount of values

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter, insert

When I register users w. facebook I enter everything I receive from fb into my user table, but sometimes there are blank columns such as 'bio'  , whats the best way to do a insert when your unsure which values will be sent over in a post request to my php api .

p.s im using codeigniter for my rest API if that makes things any easier.

Comment: You can either specify the fields in your `insert` column list, or you put placeholders (`null` values) in your `values` list

Comment: Post your table schema.

Comment: Cant specify them in advance bc i never know which will be blank , but im doing the null values way now . Just fig id ask and see if that was a acceptable means of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set all the values that don't matter to nullable then pass everything possible.

Basically without a table structure it's tough to answer this question but what you're going to do is set everything to null before getting the data, like this:

```
$data = array(
    'fbId'=>null,
    'email'=>null,
    'someOtherData'=>null,
    'yetMoreData'=>null
);
$data = $this->whateverYouAreDoingToGetFBData;
$this->db->insert('users',$data);
```

Obviously you don't want all fields null, but if you set your array BEFORE getting the Facebook data, then only overwrite the values that are supplied by FB then you're fine.

Honestly this is a pretty horrible idea, decide which data you want and go from there, I'm pretty sure you don't need absolutely everything that FB will supply, nor are people going to sign up if it sees you're asking for everything. Think about when you get that app popup, would you say yes if the app wanted to know your entire FB history?